# Multiple fastcgi projects as subdomains for nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I have directory containing FastCGI projects, to be more specific different versions of the same project. For example, there are `ver1` and `ver2` directories located at `/some/dir/project/` and I want them to be `ver1.project.example.com` and `ver2.project.example.com` respectively.

How should I do it with nginx without creating different configs for each version and assuming that new versions may be added dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project`:

```
server {
  server_name ~^(?<version>\w+)\.project\.example\.com;
  root /some/dir/project/$version;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

adding a new version directory at `/some/dir/project/version99` will automatically make it available at `version99.project.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the multiple config issue., it can be solved using an nginx inclusion file `include fastcgi_params;`. I don't know about variable server and socket locations, however, you should probably use multiple clauses for that. To make things quicker you could write something like `add-fcgi-subdomain.sh`. I resolved this issue once using templates for nginx configs and shell scripts to generate them from /var/www.